# In Metal, what performance advantages are there, if any, to using vertex descriptors and the [[stage_in]] qualifier?

Tags: shader, performance, vertex-buffer-object

Metal seems to provide two very different ways to access vertex data in your vertex shader. You can:

1. Create an `MTLVertexDescriptor` object, which describes vertex shader inputs, including per-vertex, per-instance, and constant data of basically any Metal-supported primitive type, and compile it into an `MTLRenderPipelineState`. The inputs you describe map to indexed attributes in a single `struct`, which you declare as the `[[stage_in]]` argument of a vertex function.

**OR**

2. Use the `[[vertex_id]]` and `[[instance_id]]` inputs to a vertex function as indices into user-defined buffers of arbitrary data.

The first option is very reminiscent of a classical VBO-centric rendering pipeline, while the second option is a very compute-shader-like approach. Personally, I prefer the second approach, but I'm concerned as to whether it offers the same performance as the first.

Comment: This page probably has the answer: https://metalbyexample.com/vertex-descriptors/